# WPF: Ordering and Displaying ListView SelectedItems in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a ListView with SelectionMode=Multiple and two TextBoxes. One should display the top-most selected item, one should display the bottom most selected item. I am also working using the MVVM design pattern.

The issues are as follows:

1. "SelectedItems" is indexed from the first selection point - so the SelectedItems[0] can be the bottom-most selected item, which is undesirable. I want the top-most item to display in the top box and the bottom-most item to display in the bottom box.
2. I can't seem to reference SelectedItems[ SelectedItems.Count - 1] from the XAML in order to display the last selected item.

Here's a look at my current XAML:

```
<ListView x:Name="myListView" ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}" 
              SelectionMode="Multiple">         

<TextBox x:Name="topTextBox"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" 
                 Text="{Binding ElementName=myListView, Path=SelectedItems[0].ID}" />


<TextBox x:Name="bottomTextBox" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3"   
                 Text="{Binding ElementName=myListView, Path=SelectedItems[SelectedItems.Count-1].ID}" />
```

I'm not sure what the best approach to take is.

Comment: Is your output pane showing a Data error?

Comment: Yes, it won't work with SelectedItems.Count-1. However, I'm more interested in point #1, the design decision that needs to be made.

Comment: As you pointed out, you can't rely on indexing. I would go for a `Converter` or use code-behind events. In both cases you have find first and last element of your list under current sort conditions.

Comment: @user2306362, for MVVM this type of customized view would be implemented as two properties in the VM that are calculated and raise notify events.  The ListView needs a SelectedValue property in the VM, and it needs IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem=true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I settled on is as follows:

I used the interactive namespace (Don't forget to reference the DLL) and the following XAML:

```
xmlns:interact="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"


<TextBox x:Name="startTextBox"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" 
                 Text="{Binding LatestSelectedItem}" />


 <ListView x:Name="myListView" ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}" 
              SelectionMode="Extended" >

        <interact:Interaction.Triggers>
            <interact:EventTrigger EventName="MouseUp"> <!-- Alternatively, OnSelectionChanged -->
                <interact:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MyListViewSelectionChangedCommand}" 
                                              CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=myListView, Path=SelectedItems}" />
            </interact:EventTrigger>
        </interact:Interaction.Triggers>
</ListView>
```

Then I provided appropriate Properties in my ViewModel, along with the following command:

```
    private void MyListView_SelectionChanged(object param)
    {
        IList selectedItems = (IList)param;
        List<MyViewModel> myList = selectedItems.OfType<MyViewModel>().ToList();
        if (myList.Count > 0)
        {
            myList.Sort(); // Implement comparator on MyViewModel
            LatestSelectedItem = myList[myList.Count-1];
        }
    }
```

Works fine.